# OneToOneField is nor related

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

this me again. I have some trouble with my code. I made a form from ModelForm which have a model with 8 attributes, but i want to user fill only one of them,and one from the system. The one that user fill is okay, but the one filled with system is not working.

> models.py

```
class SeminarProposal(md.Model):
    # diisi oleh mahasiswa
    fileProposal = models.FileField()

    # This is the one is filled with system
    proposal = models.OneToOneField(Proposal,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name="propSid",
                                    unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    masabimbingan = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # disi oleh admin
    tanggal = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True,null=True)
    tempat = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    # diisi oleh dosen pembimbing
    dospemsetuju = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    # diisi oleh kaprodi
    penguji1 = models.ForeignKey(Dosen,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="penguji1",
                                 blank=True, null=True)
    penguji2 = models.ForeignKey(Dosen,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="penguji2",
                                 blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Sidang untuk " + self.proposal.judul
```

> view.py

```
def daftarSeminar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormSeminar(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.cleaned_data['proposal']
            print(request.user)
            prop = Proposal.objects.get(akun=request.user)
            form.proposal = prop
            print(form.proposal) #to confirm that this is not None
            form.save()
            return redirect('proposal:bimbingan')
        else:
            return render(request, 'sidprop.html' , {'oke': 'oke'})
        return redirect('proposal:index')
```

> form.py

```
class FormSeminar(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SeminarProposal
        fields = ['fileProposal','proposal']
```

Thanks in advance. Terimakasih.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you have any errors to show?

Comment: the error is that the relations is turn to null. There is no error with the process like exception or similar, but the result is when I want to relate ` prop = Proposal.objects.get(akun=request.user)
            form.proposal = prop
            print(form.proposal) #to confirm that this is not None`

Comment: having a bit of trouble understanding your requirement. I think it would be wise to have the variables converted to English for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the form data, get the object from form and change the object's data:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    prop = Proposal.objects.get(akun=request.user)
    obj.proposal = prop
    obj.save()
    return redirect('proposal:bimbingan')
```